# libusb libusb_bulk_transfer always receives 1 byte

Tags: usb, libusb

I have this code that reads data from an USB device:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <libusb.h>
#include <string.h>

#define VENDOR_ID      0x10C4
#define PRODUCT_ID     0xEA60
#define IN_ENDPOINT    0x81

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int err = libusb_init(NULL);

    libusb_device_handle *device_handle = NULL;
    unsigned char value_str[64];
    device_handle = libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(NULL, VENDOR_ID, PRODUCT_ID);

    libusb_set_auto_detach_kernel_driver(device_handle, 1);

    err = libusb_claim_interface(device_handle, 0);

    int transfered = 0;
    unsigned char out[6] = {'A', 'T', '$', 'S', 'R', '\r'};
    libusb_bulk_transfer(device_handle, 0x01, out, 6, &transfered, 0);

    int res = libusb_bulk_transfer(device_handle, IN_ENDPOINT, value_str, 64, &transfered, 0);

    while (res == 0)
    {
        if (transfered == 0) continue;
        std::cout << "Reading Successful: ";

        for (int i = 0; i < transfered; i++) 
        {
            std::cout << value_str[i];
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
        res = libusb_bulk_transfer(device_handle, IN_ENDPOINT, value_str, 64, &transfered, 0);
    }

    libusb_release_interface(device_handle, 0);
    libusb_close(device_handle);

    libusb_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Everything works fine except that in 99% of cases it reads only 1 byte (however device sands more, like 19-20). There were few times when I was able to read all string, but in most cases it was several 1 byte-reads.

Here is the output:

```
Reading Successful: A
Reading Successful: T
Reading Successful: $
Reading Successful: S
Reading Successful: R
Reading Successful:
Reading Successful: -
Reading Successful: 4
Reading Successful: 1
Reading Successful: 8
Reading Successful: 0
Reading Successful: 0
Reading Successful: 0
Reading Successful: 7
Reading Successful: 9
Reading Successful: 5
Reading Successful: x
Reading Successful: x
Reading Successful: x
Reading Successful: :
Reading Successful: h
Reading Successful: e
Reading Successful: l
Reading Successful: p
Reading Successful: :
Reading Successful: b
Reading Successful: a
Reading Successful: t
Reading Successful: o
Reading Successful: k
Reading Successful:
Reading Successful:
```

So the question is why I always (almost) receive 1 byte of data and is it possible to configure my program somehow with libusb API to make it read all incoming data?

Comment: I'm sending 4 bytes from android to host pc, I received only 1 bytes `&transferred`, please let us know if you fixed your problem..thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't solved the problem. I implemented kind of workaround by building message byte by byte. I know that every command from the device ends with 0xA 0xD symbols, so I just place all incoming bytes to the buffer until I receive 0xA 0xD

Comment: I fixed my problem, I'm able to stream camera photos to main app ( Host PC c++ ), by sending the bytes via usb followed by 3 bytes ( as end of an image bytes ), now I can stream to PC windows host via usb

Comment: In case I send bytes length before the data ( from android ) I receive `1 byte` and not the 4 bytes as a length of array, so what i did, streaming the bytes array first, then 3 bytes as `END` of image